# Spark Version in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

How do I determine which version of Spark I'm running on Databricks?  I would like to try koalas, but when I try `import databricks.koalas`, it returns a `"No module named databricks"` error message.  When I try `from databricks import koalas`, it returns the same message.

Comment: any reason you are not installing koalas from pypi ?

Comment: I was not aware of pypi.  All the references I've seen point to "from databricks import koalas."  I just tried "from pypi import koalas" and it returned 'no module pypi found.'

Comment: @karthik can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: version of spark can be verified from the cluster configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Koalas is only included into the Databricks Runtime versions 7.x and higher. It's not included into DBR 6.x.  You can find version of Databricks Runtime in the UI, if you click on dropdown on top of the notebook.

You can check version of Koalas in the [Databricks Runtime release notes](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/releases.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Databricks notebook the easy way is to
type below in the cell, works for python/Scala.

print (spark.version)